# How to play sound once when two sprite collide in andengine?

Tags: android, andengine

Well I'm working with ball game , Every thing is working fine , Now i want to add Sound when the two balls collide each other .

I tried the following code but the sound is being repeated.I want it will play only once when collision start & not at collision maintained.

**In onCreateResources:**

```
SoundFactory.setAssetBasePath("sfx/");
try {
     mSound = SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(getSoundManager(), this, "coll2.m4a");
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And added below code in **onAccelerationChanged**(AccelerationData pAccelerationData)

```
if (face.collidesWith(face1) || face.collidesWith(face2))
                        {
                            mSound.play();
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `boolean` to check if the sprites have already collided. The code would look something like this.-

```
if (face.collidesWith(face1) || face.collidesWith(face2)) { 
    if (!colliding) {
        colliding = true;
        mSound.play(); 
    }
} else {
    colliding = false;
}
```